# jQuery syntax between versions for sizing select boxes

Tags: jquery

The following code works in jQuery 1.8.1 but not versions after that. Can you assist with what tweek is necessary?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').width(500); 
});</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine in 1.11 http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/63fr6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use the `.css()` method instead of width:

```
$('select').css('width','500');
```